# How to conditionally format substring only in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

Say in A1 contains `"boy"`, in B1 contains `"This is a boy"`, I want to search substring in `B1` based on `A1`, and format the substring only ("boy" only) in `B1`, not the whole sentence in `B1`.
If using `=Search(A1,B1)` or `=Isnumber(Search(A1,B1))` in Conditonal Formatting, it will format the whole sentence, that is not what I want. Please kindly tell me how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: As my best known, that is not possible.

Comment: Thank harun24hr for editing, it seems more readable.  Is it really a mission impossible?

Comment: I am afraid it is no possible with Conditional Formatting, it is designed to format the whole cell. Is it ok for you to use VBA?

Comment: No, I don't know about VBA. Using VBA can solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is only possible using VBA. Try the following (crude) sub:

```
Sub bold()
On Error GoTo continue 'Otherwise you will receive an error if the substring is missing
For Each cell In Selection
    myString = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    mySearch = cell
    mySearch_length = Len(mySearch)
    mySearch_startPos = WorksheetFunction.Search(mySearch, myString)
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Characters(Start:=mySearch_startPos, Length:=mySearch_length).Font.FontStyle = "Bold" 'Change to something else as you wish
continue:
Next cell
End Sub
```

This expects the same setup of the spreadsheet you defined above (with the *substring to be formatted* to the left of the *string*) and requires that you select the substrings before running the macro.

Comment: It is a pity that I don't know about VBA, but thank you for your help. May be it is helpful to someone who have the same problem.

Comment: A simple google yielded this link: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/. Check it out and see if it gets you going. VBA can unlock all sorts of magic that can save loads of time given a little effort.

Comment: Ok, that's great, I think I have to learn VBA to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, a-burge, I've read the webpage you recommended, I tried it and it works like a magic, thank you very much.